# Prove that there exists a scalar potential $f( \mathbf{ x} )$ such that $\mathbf{ F } = − \nabla f$ [2012 11c]

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> **Question:** If F is an irrotational vector field (i.e. $ \nabla \times \mathbf{ F  = 0 }$ everywhere), prove that there
>   exists a scalar potential $f( \mathbf{ x} )$ such that $\mathbf{ F } = − \nabla f$.

I remember the theorem that $\text{ curl grad } f \; \mathbf{   = 0 }$ (from Stewart P1063). So if I substitute  $\mathbf{ F } = − \nabla f$ into this theorem, then $\text{ curl } ( − \nabla f) \; \mathbf{   = 0 } \iff -\text{ curl } (\nabla f) \; \mathbf{   = 0 }$, the latter of which is true.

Is this the proof? If not, would someone please help or refer me to one?

Comment: [2012 11c] is a reference to...?

Comment: @user37238 I would guess [this](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/pastpapers/2012/ia/index.html). Seems about right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbf{F}$ is an irrotational vector field on a simply connected domain $D$, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=\mathbf{0}$ everywhere in $D$.

Define $f_C(\mathbf{x})=-\int_{C}{F(\mathbf{x'}) \cdot d\mathbf{x'}}$ where $C$ is a curve from a fixed point $\mathbf{x_0}$ to $\mathbf{x}$. We show that $f_{\mathbf{C}}$ does not depend on $C$.

Indeed, consider distinct curves $C_1, C_2$ from $\mathbf{x_0}$ to $\mathbf{x}$. Let $-C_2$ represent the curve $C_2$ but in the opposite direction. Then the curve $C$ formed by combining $C_1$ and $-C_2$ bounds a surface $S$ in $D$ (Surface lies in $D$ as $D$ is simply connected).

We apply Stoke's theorem to get

$$0=\int_{S}{(\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot d\mathbf{S}}=\int_{\partial S}{F(\mathbf{x'}) \cdot d\mathbf{x'}}=\int_{C_1}{F(\mathbf{x'}) \cdot d\mathbf{x'}}-\int_{C_2}{F(\mathbf{x'}) \cdot d\mathbf{x'}}=f_{C_2}(\mathbf{x})-f_{C_1}(\mathbf{x})$$

Thus $f_C$ does not depend on $C$, as desired. We may thus define $f(\mathbf{x})=-\int_{C}{F(\mathbf{x'}) \cdot d\mathbf{x'}}$ which is well defined by above.

Now consider a small perturbation $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \mathbf{x}+\delta \mathbf{x}$, $C \mapsto C+\delta C$

$$f(\mathbf{x}+\delta \mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x})+\nabla f \cdot \delta \mathbf{x} +o(|\delta \mathbf{x}|)$$

$$f(\mathbf{x}+\delta \mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{x})=-\int_{\delta C}{F(\mathbf{x'}) \cdot d\mathbf{x'}}=-F(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \delta \mathbf{x}+o(|\delta \mathbf{x}|)$$

Comparing, we get $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla f$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks. Can your answer be simplified in any way? My proof doesn't have to be "too" rigorous.

Comment: @LePressentiment I guess you might try handwaving the part showing that $f$ is well-defined by just claiming that it easily follows from Stoke's theorem.